# React reducers, state not updating immediately

Tags: reactjs, redux-reducers

i am working on `createContext` and `reducers`, with reducers i am updating state value, but it is not updating value at a time, i did `console.log(user);`  in `onSubmitSave()`, but in console log i am not getting its updated state at a time, i can see it works when i clicked on signin again, here i have attached my whole code, can anyone please look into it, and help me to resolve this issue ?

auth.js

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

    const AuthContext = createContext({
      user: null,
      hasLoginError: false,
      login: () => null,
      logout: () => null
    });
    
    export default AuthContext;
```

signin.js

```
// Login button Click
  async function onSubmitSave(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const messages = {
      'itemUsername.required': 'Username cannot be empty.',
      'itemPassword.required': 'Password cannot be empty.',
    };
    const rules = {
      itemUsername: 'required',
      itemPassword: 'required|string',

    };
    validateAll(state, rules, messages)
      .then(async () => {
        let data = await login(itemUsername, itemPassword);
        console.log(data);
        console.log("sdsds");
        console.log(user);
        setUserData(user);
      })
      .catch(errors => {
        const formattedErrors = {

        };

        errors.forEach(error => formattedErrors[error.field] = error.message);

        setState({
          ...state,
          errors: formattedErrors
        });
      })

  }
  // End Login
```

App.js

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case "login": {
      const { username, password } = action.payload;

      return {
        ...state,
        hasLoginError: false,
        user: {
          id: 1,
          username: USERNAME,
          firstName: "Dev",
          lastName: "To"
        }
      };


    }
    case "logout":
      return {
        ...state,
        user: null
      };
    default:
      throw new Error(`Invalid action type: ${action.type}`);
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you also add `setUserData` method?

Comment: but it will only works in Signin

Comment: where you defining this USERNAME variable in App.js ?

Comment: yes right now i have passed static value in it

Comment: you can try removing the `async` and `await` and returning `login(itemUsername, itemPassword);` from first `then` block. You can chain another `then` statement with `data` as it's argument, inside which you can try logging the data and setting the user.